# Setting up Jasmine/karma for angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am lightly following this guide - http://paislee.io/testing-angularjs-with-grunt-karma-and-jasmine/ - and having a few issues as follows:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngRoute due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngRoute' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I installed everything as it told me to and found another pretty basic example of setting up a test(this is my first time implementing so I'm starting small), the test looks like so

```
describe('Unit: MainCtrl', function() {
// Load the module with MainCtrl
beforeEach(module('myApp'));

var ctrl, scope;
// inject the $controller and $rootScope services
// in the beforeEach block
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
// Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
scope = $rootScope.$new();
// Create the controller
ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
  $scope: scope
});
}));

it('should create $scope.greeting when calling sayHello', 
function() {
  expect(scope.greeting).toBeUndefined();
  scope.sayHello();
  expect(scope.greeting).toEqual("Hello Ari");
 });
```

})

And in the controller it's just

```
 $scope.name = "Ari";
$scope.sayHello = function() {
$scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
}
```

(this is from http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/19 )

I have my app set up and controllers in separate folders, using a regular ng-route structure, I'm thinking this maybe is the issue? I'm using grunt karma for this - here is the task just incase it's helpful.

```
  karma: {  
      unit: {
        options: {
          frameworks: ['jasmine'],
          singleRun: true,
          browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
          files: [
            'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/scripts/**/*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

I could use some help, this is my first time attempting this, I would LOVE to get some automated testing in place. Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include ngRoute in your files list in the karma conf. The error message says as much.

```
karma: {  
      unit: {
        options: {
          frameworks: ['jasmine'],
          singleRun: true,
          browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
          files: [
            'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-route.js',
            'app/scripts/**/*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not included ngroute module, as there is some dependency on this module.

There should be a bower component

`'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',`

Install this bower component and add this line to karma config.

Check for other module too.

Comment: I overlooked the simplest things thinking it was something more complex. Thank you!!